# graph disconnected error when trying visualizing and obtaining feature map nested model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to obtain feature maps of the model which include three nested models (functional model). when I create another model to do this task throw graph disconnected error. I used the below snippet. my purpose is to obtain a feature map in a nested model after feed input for prediction.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs =my_model.input, outputs = my_model.layers[5].output)
```

My model architecture is below

```
from os import name
import NumPy as np
import tensorflow.keras as kr
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow_addons.optimizers import AdamW
import tensorflow.keras.backend as k
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import activations
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from classification_models.keras import Classifiers
import torchvision.models as tmodels


# import from Classifier file in directory path


class DeepRhythmModel:

    def __init__(self,
                 motion_magnified_input_size=(1, 300)
                 , MMST_Map_size=(300, 25, 3)  # frames:temporal , block:spatial , rgb signal
                 , row_col_blocks_number=(5, 5)

                 , lr_rate=None
                 , batch_size=32
                 , num_classes=1
                 , weight_decay=None
                 , pretrained=False
                 , exist_meso=True
                 ):
        """
        initialize Model variable
        Args:
            input_size: (T,N,3)
            row_col_blocks_number
            ppg_map:
            motion_magnified_input:
            lr_rate:
            epochs:
        """
        self.weight_decay = weight_decay
        self.motion_magnified_input_size = motion_magnified_input_size
        self.MMST_Map_size = MMST_Map_size

        self.row_col_blocks_number = row_col_blocks_number
        self.lr_rate = lr_rate
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        # CREATE PRIOR SPATIAL ATTENTION LIST
        r, c = row_col_blocks_number
        self.pretrained = pretrained
        self.exist_meso = exist_meso
        self.num_classes = num_classes


    def build_model(self):

        #### INPUT ####
        prior_spatial_attention_input = layers.Input(
            shape=(1, self.row_col_blocks_number[0] * self.row_col_blocks_number[1]))
        MMST_Map_input = layers.Input(shape=self.MMST_Map_size)
        if self.exist_meso:
            frame_level_temporal_attention_input = layers.Input(shape=self.motion_magnified_input_size,
                                                                )
        block_level_temporal_attention_input = layers.Reshape(
            (self.MMST_Map_size[0], self.MMST_Map_size[1] * self.MMST_Map_size[2]))(MMST_Map_input)

        ### Block Level Temporal Attention Model

        blk_level_tmp_atn_inpt = self.block_level_temporal_attention_model()(block_level_temporal_attention_input)


        ### Adaptive Spatial Attention
        adp_sp_atn_out = self.adptive_spatial_attention()(MMST_Map_input)

        ## (tf + tb)
        if self.exist_meso:
            temporal = layers.Add()([blk_level_tmp_atn_inpt, frame_level_temporal_attention_input])
        else:
            temporal = blk_level_tmp_atn_inpt

        ## (sa + sp)
        spatial = layers.Add()([adp_sp_atn_out, prior_spatial_attention_input])

        # Attention map
        attention = layers.Dot(axes=(2, 1))([layers.Permute((2, 1))(temporal), spatial])

        gray_attention = layers.Reshape((attention.shape[1], attention.shape[2], 1))(attention)
        rgb_attention = tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(gray_attention)

        # Multiple rgb attention & MMST_Map_input
        resnet_ipt = layers.Multiply()([rgb_attention, MMST_Map_input])
        final_output = self.resnet18()(resnet_ipt)

        if self.exist_meso:
            main_model = models.Model(
                inputs=[prior_spatial_attention_input, MMST_Map_input, frame_level_temporal_attention_input],
                outputs=[final_output], name='DeepRhythmModel')
        else:
            main_model = models.Model(inputs=[prior_spatial_attention_input, MMST_Map_input], outputs=[final_output],
                                      name='DeepRhythmModel')

        optimizer = AdamW(weight_decay = self.weight_decay, learning_rate = self.lr_rate)
        main_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
        main_model.summary(expand_nested=True)

        return main_model

    # Create adaptive_spatial_attention module
    def adptive_spatial_attention(self):
        inpt = layers.Input(shape = self.MMST_Map_size)
        x = layers.Conv2D(64, (15, 1), activation='relu')(inpt)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(15, 1))(x)
        x = layers.Flatten()(x)
        x = layers.Dense(25, activation="tanh")(x)
        output = layers.Reshape((1, x.shape[1]))(x)
        return models.Model(inputs=inpt, outputs=output, name='adptive_spatial_attention')

    # BUILD BLOCK-LEVEL TEMPORAL ATTENTION MODEL
    def block_level_temporal_attention_model(self):

        inpt = layers.Input(shape=(self.MMST_Map_size[0], self.MMST_Map_size[1] * self.MMST_Map_size[2]))
        x = layers.LSTM(units = 300)(inpt)
        output = layers.Reshape((1, x.shape[1]))(x)
        return models.Model(inputs=inpt, outputs=output, name='block_level_temporal_attention_model')

    def resnet18(self):

        ResNet18, preprocess_input = Classifiers.get('resnet18')
        inpt = layers.Input(shape=self.MMST_Map_size)
        if self.pretrained:
            base_model = ResNet18(input_shape=(300, 25, 3), include_top=False)(inpt)
        else:
            base_model = ResNet18(input_shape=(300, 25, 3), include_top=False, weights=None)(inpt)
        x = layers.Flatten()(base_model)
        output = layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
        return models.Model(inputs=inpt, outputs=output, name='resnet18')
```

To create the model this snippet used

```
DeepRhythmOBJ = DeepRhythmModel(lr_rate=lr_rate, batch_size = batch_size,weight_decay=weight_decay, pretrained=False)
new_model= DeepRhythmOBJ.build_model()
```